# Google Hangouts Api

Tags: android, api, google-api

I've recently noticed that Google has replaced the Google Talk application with Google Hangouts. I was wondering if there were any APIs available for Google Hangouts? I've searched online but it kind of got confusing because there is also a hangout feature within Google+.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google+ Hangouts is really Google Hangouts.

Have a look at the official documentation here: https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/

Google is trying to combine a lot of their products together, so you'll be able to use a lot of features throughout different applications.